# Add a file to /etc/yum.repos.d to install Oracle JDK 1.6.0-45 from yum?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I have a fresh RedHat 6.5 virtual machine on Amazon Web Services (EC2), its repos look like this currently:

```
[root@ip-172-31-11-112 tmp]# ls -1 /etc/yum.repos.d/
redhat-rhui-client-config.repo
redhat-rhui.repo
rhel-source.repo
rhui-load-balancers.conf
```

I need to to be able to install the **Oracle** jdk 1.6.0.45 from the yum repo, I think I need to have a new file in the above directory for this to happen but not sure what the contents of this file should look like, maybe something like the file below, but not sure what goes in the baseurl section below?

```
[oracle 1.6.0-45 jdk]
name = Oracle 1.6.045 JDK
baseurl = ???
enabled = 1
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can't be install from repository respectively I don't know any public repository with Oracle/Sun JDK.

You can follow [this guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu server I can install it with a set of given commands:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Then add the Java repository:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

And then install Java:

```
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This tutorial helped me a lot: [Install and set-up JAVA & Grails on an Ubuntu 14.04 Linux VPS](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-and-set-up-java-grails-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-linux-vps/)

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).